# Modal popup not able to close for the quick action used VF page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Account" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="author" content=""/>
        <title>Select Pricing </title>
        <apex:includeLightning />


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lightningContainer"> </div>
        <script>
            $Lightning.use("c:SelectPricingApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:SelectPricingcmp",{"recordId" : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}'},
                    "lightningContainer",
                    function(cmp) {

                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body> 
</apex:page>
```

Quick action created with VF Page and trying to close on Save but not working

Comment: Quick action created with VF Page and trying to close on Save but not working

Comment: $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
tried above

Comment: var element = document.getElementsByClassName("DESKTOP uiContainerManager"); 
             element.forEach(function(e, t) {
                $A.util.addClass(e, 'slds-hide');
             });